# Каков общепринятый подход по работе с исключениями в JS?

Tags: javascript, исключения, обработка-ошибок

Мне хочется узнать каков стандартный подход, а не про техническую составляющую, т.е. не про то как бросить или как перехватить или повторно бросить исключение.

В каждом языке программирования есть свои стандартные подходы по обработке ошибок. К примеру, смотря на код написанном на Python-е вижу `except BaseExcepiton` и мне становится ясно, что автор кода перехватывает встроенные исключения. Если же пишу некий модуль в котором хочу сообщить о проблеме в том модуле, то унаследуюсь от базового класса `Exception`, который как раз предназначен для пользовательских типов исключений.

Существует ли и в JS-мире разработки стандартный способ по работе с исключениями? Конечно же, технически можно написать все что угодно и средства языка многое позволяют. Но мне хочется узнать именно стандартный, общепринятый подход и его, к сожалению, пока не знаю и не вижу.

Comment: Не проще ли почитать документацию: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch . А еще лучше спецификацию. Есть базовый конструктор Error. От него "наследованы" другие конструкторы... Вы можете создать свой. После перехвата, можете определить тип исключения. Дайте определение НЕобщепринятому подходу, не понятно что конкретно вам непонятно.

Comment: Мозилловский гайдлайн [ничего специального не говорит](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Control_flow_and_error_handling#exception_handling_statements). Гугловый же [рекомендует](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html#features-exceptions) "Prefer throwing exceptions over ad-hoc error-handling approaches (such as passing an error container reference type, or returning an object with an error property)."